# When using multiple inheritance, why is it asking for a 'self' argument for one class but not for the other?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I am quite new to Python inheritance, and am working on some code that I can't seem to understand:

```
class ContextMsg:
    def __init__(self, playtime=None):
        self.playtime = playtime

class Mixture:
    def __init__(self):
        self.subcontx = {}
        self.context = ContextMsg()

class Subplayer: 
    def __init__(self, outer, inner, **kwargs):
        self.inner = inner
        self.outer = outer
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

class GameControl(Subplayer, Mixture): 
    def __init__(self, outer, inner, **kwargs):
        Subplayer.__init__(outer, inner, **kwargs)
        Mixture.__init__()
```

So in `class GameControl`, for its constructor, the `Mixture.__init__()` ; it says that it needs a `self` argument?

I don't understand why this is the case, because for `Subplayer.__init__` it is not asking for a `self` argument?

Comment: Both calls need a `self`, it is just that in the first call the IDE considers `outer` to be the thing passed in as `self`. The code as shown here breaks when calling it via `GameControl({}, {})`. (Downvote because you apparently never actually ran the code)

Comment: Please update your question with how you are creating an instance of `GameController`

Comment: How are you using this where it isn't failing on the `Subplayer.__init__` call?

Comment: because the `__init__` is called by a class and not an instance. Notice the your current way to subclass may have problem with _diamond_ pattern

Answer (score 1):

this is the right way to implement `GameControl.__init__`

```py
class GameControl(Subplayer, Mixture): 
    def __init__(self, outer, inner, **kwargs):
        Subplayer.__init__(self, outer, inner, **kwargs)
        Mixture.__init__(self)
```

Comment: Really the _right_ way is with consistent use of `super`. `GameControl#__init__` should just have to invoke the _next_ implementation.